# filesystemwatcher multiple files

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a doubt using FileSystemWatcher in C#.
I need to be notified when a file is created in a specified folder, but the problem is if I create multiple files at the same time multiple events are beeing fired and I need that the code only continues if the previous file was processed and not process multiple files at the same time.

Any clue how to do that?

Many thanks

Comment: can't provide pseudo-code for this, but you'd probably have to have the method that's triggered execute in a separate thread and use thread lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudo-code:

```
bool wasLastObjectProcessed = true

function onFileWatcherCreateFile
    lock wasLastObjectProcessed
        if wasLastObjectProcessed and processFile(file)
            #do some code here that you need to do if it is processed
        else
           wasLastObjectProcessed = false
        endif
    endlock
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a `Queue<T>`
- Enqueue in the `FileSystemWatcher`
- Dequeue in another thread

Make sure you use it in a thread safe manner using `Queue.Synchronized`

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle filesystemwatchers is that whenever an event fires I add details of that event to a queue. I then set a timer for 5 seconds time to the process the queue. This timer will hopefully ensure that files have finished copying and that all operations are complete (ie multiple events being raised).

When processing the queue you can use a lock to make sure the queue is only processed by one thread at any given time and then you can just take stuff off the queue and process it until the queue is empty and then you're done.

If you want to be able to add to the queue while its processing you might need to do some appropriate locking.